# how to test a for-loop iteration in apex?

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

Hi I tried this code but I am getting an error can any tell me how to solve this error.

```
 public class updatecon{

        public id tobeEdited{get; set;}
        list<contact> lstcontact = [SELECT ID,name, Firstname,lastname,email,phone from contact];

        public void saveRecord(){
            Contact tobeupdated;
            for(Contact temp : lstcontact){
                if(temp.id==tobeEdited){
                    tobeupdated = temp;   
                    break;
                }
            }
            update tobeupdated;
            tobeEdited = null;
        }
    }
```

Test class:

```
@istest
public class testupdatecon{
    public static testMethod void testMyController(){
Contact ccc = new Contact(accountid=aa.id,Firstname='bob',lastname='test',email='test@example.com',phone='0101010101');
insert ccc;
System.test.startTest();
updatecon controller  = new updatecon();
controller.tobeEdited = ccc.Id;
update ccc;
controller.saveRecord();
System.test.stopTest();
  }
}
```

Error:

```
temp|null
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you getting an error in line 86? Your debug shows temp is null. Which probably means that your `lstcontact` contains null value. Can you debug your `lstcontact`. You can make sure that a null value is not added into `lstcontact` or check `if(temp!=null)` in line 86.

Comment: @manjit_singh : IF lstContact is null then it will not cover line no - 85 itself. The problem is with the line 86 condition

Comment: @Nilesh I did not meant that the list is null. I am saying that it may contains one value which is null and it gets assigned to temp. Like: `lstcontact` = {null}. Hope this clears your doubt ;)

Comment: Now i updated my debug log also could you please review that log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]You should replace your test class with this code

@istest
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
public class testupdatecon{

```
public static testMethod void testMyController(){
    Account aa = new Account(name='test');
```

Contact ccc = new

Contact(accountid=aa.id,Firstname='bob',lastname='test',email='test@example.com',phone='0101010101');

insert ccc;

System.test.startTest();

updatecon controller  = new updatecon();

controller.tobeEdited = ccc.Id;

update ccc;

controller.saveRecord();

System.test.stopTest();

}

}

this code working and code coverage is 100%

Comment: I changed my code with your code even i m getting error:" [91]|System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []"

Comment: it's impossible if your class code same as you write above . see these screenshots

Comment: Trigger on account will be an active thats why showed error now its getting 100% thank you

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `tobeEdited`, but you never instantiate it.  You need to instatiate it, even if you set it to null to begin with.

I don't really know what you are trying to do so I can't tell you exactly what you should do but something like this will at least get rid of the error.

```
public string tobeEdited {get; set;} {tobeEdited = '';}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things to do with your code :

```
public class updatecon{

        public id tobeEdited{get; set;}
        list<contact> lstcontact = [SELECT ID,name, Firstname,lastname,email,phone from contact LIMIT 10]; ////****See Changes
```

//HERE In SOQL you should have at least one "WHERE" condition or "LIMIT" --to avoid Governer Limits/other SOQL errors

```
        public void saveRecord(){
            Contact tobeupdated = new Contact(); //**** See Changes
            for(Contact temp : lstcontact){
                if(temp.id==tobeEdited){
                    tobeupdated = temp;   
                    break;
                }
            }
            update tobeupdated;
            tobeEdited = null;
        }
    }
```

Please, correct me If I am saying something wrong.

Comment: You will get an error if you try to compare to `tobeEdited.Id`.  `tobeEdited` is initialized as an ID, so you are saying Id.Id, which will throw an error.

Comment: updated. Thank you for correction; Confusion because of the naming conventions :P